# Interpreter in Java for S.I.L.O.S., a custom language

Tags: java, performance, interpreter, language-design

I designed and implemented a custom language. After @LeakyNun refactored it to improve speed, it looks like this. I personally like it right now, but is there any more hyperoptimizations for both readability and performance?

```
/*
 *Feel free to modify and distribute the code and all relevant documentation
* This code is provided as is and the author
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * S.I.L.O.S interpeter
 *
 * @author rohan
 */
public class Silos {
    /**
     * This integer[] represents the heap of memory which can be addressed
     */
    private static int[] mem;
    private static String[] texts;

    private final static int GOTO = 0 << 8;
    private final static int GOSUB = 1 << 8;
    private final static int RETURN = 2 << 8;
    private final static int PRINTLINE = 3 << 8;
    private final static int PRINTCHAR = 4 << 8;
    private final static int PRINT = 5 << 8;
    private final static int PRINTINT = 6 << 8;
    private final static int SET = 7 << 8;
    private final static int GET = 8 << 8;
    private final static int IF = 9 << 8;
    private final static int READIO = 10 << 8;
    private final static int RAND = 11 << 8;
    private final static int LOADLINE = 12 << 8;
    private final static int CANVAS = 13 << 8;
    private final static int WAIT = 14 << 8;
    private final static int DRAW = 15 << 8;
    private final static int PEN = 16 << 8;
    private final static int BIND = 17 << 8;
    private final static int REFRESH = 18 << 8;
    private final static int ADD = 19 << 8;
    private final static int SUB = 20 << 8;
    private final static int MUL = 21 << 8;
    private final static int DIV = 22 << 8;
    private final static int MOD = 23 << 8;
    private final static int ABS = 24 << 8;
    private final static int POW = 25 << 8;
    private final static int AND = 26 << 8;
    private final static int OR = 27 << 8;
    private final static int XOR = 28 << 8;
    private final static int XNOR = 29 << 8;
    private final static int NOT = 30 << 8;
    private final static int LSHIFT = 31 << 8;
    private final static int RSHIFT = 32 << 8;
    private final static int ASSIGN = 33 << 8;
    private final static int NEWOBJ = 34 << 8;
    private static final int MOVEOBJ = 35 << 8;
    private static final int PRINTINTNOLINE = 36 << 8;

    private final static int INTEGER = 0;
    private final static int VARIABLE = 1;

    private final static int ELLIPSE = 0;
    private final static int SQUARE = 1;

    /**
     * Prints out the prompt and then returns the string user types
     *
     * @param prompt the prompt for the user
     * @return the string typed into the console
     */
    public static String getStringFromSTDIN(String prompt, Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        return line;
    }

    static class Input implements KeyListener {

        static int[] bindings = new int[]{};

        public static void setNewBindings(int[] bind) {
            bindings = new int[bind.length / 2 - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < bindings.length; i++) {
                bindings[i] = evalToken(bind[i * 2 + 1], bind[i * 2 + 2], 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            for (int i = 0; i < bindings.length; i += 2) {
                if (c == bindings[i]) {
                    //System.out.println(c + ":pressed!");
                    mem[bindings[i + 1]] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

    }
    static int[] vars;

    static class Drawable {

        int x, y;
        int type;
        int width;
        int height;
        Color color = Canvas.pen;

        public Drawable(int inType, int inWidth, int inHeight) {
            type = inType;
            width = inWidth;
            height = inHeight;
        }
    }
public static String IDEFileName = "234567890-45678900ihb567890oijhb213dsa_TempFILE_v";
    /**
     * The main interpretation code
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments to be passed from the online
     * interpreter the first argument represents a fileName, and the rest
     * represent a source of input Feeding in any number of command line arguments
     * will generally disable interactivity. 
     */

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean interactive = (args.length == 0);


        int[][] program = compile(args.length==0?getStringFromSTDIN("FileName?", sc):args[0]);
        if(args.length==1){
            if(args[0].equals(IDEFileName)){
                interactive = true;
            }
        }

        int arg_index = 1;
        int ptr = 0;
        int length = program.length;
        int[] tokens = null;
        memory = mem;
//for(int[] p:program)System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(p));
//for(String s:texts)System.out.println(s);
        while (ptr < length) {
            try {
                tokens = program[ptr];//System.out.println(mem['x']);System.out.println(ptr+" "+(tokens[0]>>8));
                switch (tokens[0] & ~0b11111111) {
                    case GOTO:
                        ptr = tokens[1];
                        continue;
                    case IF:
                        ptr = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0) > 0 ? tokens[2] : ptr + 1;
                        continue;
                    case GOSUB:
                        stack.add(ptr);
                        ptr = tokens[1];
                        continue;
                    case RETURN:
                        ptr = stack.pop();
                        break;
                    case PRINTLINE:
                        System.out.println(tokens.length > 1 ? texts[tokens[1]] : "");
                        break;
                    case PRINTCHAR:
                        System.out.print((char) evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0));
                        break;
                    case NEWOBJ:
                        int type = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0);
                        int width = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 1);
                        int height = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[3], 2);
                        Drawable next = new Drawable(type, width, height);
                        Canvas.Panel.toDraw.add(next);
                        break;
                    case MOVEOBJ:
                        int index = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0);
                        int x = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 1);
                        int y = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[3], 2);

                        Drawable d = Canvas.Panel.toDraw.get(index);
                        d.x = x;
                        d.y = y;
                        break;
                    case PRINT:
                        //potential no-op
                        System.out.print(tokens.length > 1 ? texts[tokens[1]] : "");
                        break;
                    case PRINTINT:
                        System.out.println(evalToken(Silos.VARIABLE, tokens[1], 0));
                        break;
                    case PRINTINTNOLINE:
                        System.out.print(evalToken(Silos.VARIABLE, tokens[1], 0));
                        break;
                    case ASSIGN:
                        mem[tokens[1]] = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case GET:
                        mem[tokens[1]] = mem[evalToken(Silos.INTEGER, evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0), 0)];
                        break;
                    case ADD:
                        mem[tokens[1]] += evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case SUB:
                        mem[tokens[1]] -= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case MUL:
                        mem[tokens[1]] *= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case DIV:
                        mem[tokens[1]] /= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case MOD:
                        mem[tokens[1]] %= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case POW:
                        mem[tokens[1]] = (int) Math.pow(mem[tokens[1]], evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0));
                        break;
                    case ABS:
                        mem[tokens[1]] = Math.abs(mem[tokens[1]]);
                        break;
                    case AND:
                        mem[tokens[1]] &= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case OR:
                        mem[tokens[1]] |= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case XOR:
                        mem[tokens[1]] ^= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case XNOR:
                        mem[tokens[1]] ^=~ evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case NOT:
                        mem[tokens[1]] =~ mem[tokens[1]];
                        break;
                    case LSHIFT:
                        mem[tokens[1]] <<= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case RSHIFT: //signed right-shift
                        mem[tokens[1]] >>= evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 0);
                        break;
                    case SET:
                        mem[evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0)] = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 1);
                        break;
                    case READIO:
                        if (interactive) {
                            if (tokens.length > 1) {
                                mem['i'] = Integer.parseInt(getStringFromSTDIN(texts[tokens[1]], sc));
                            } else {
                                mem['i'] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                            }
                        } else {
                            mem['i'] = Integer.parseInt(args[arg_index++]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case RAND:
                        mem['r'] = (int) (Math.random() * evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0));
                        break;
                    case LOADLINE:
                        char[] in;
                        if (interactive) {
                            if (tokens.length > 1) {
                                in = getStringFromSTDIN(texts[tokens[1]], sc).toCharArray();
                            } else {
                                in = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
                            }
                        } else {
                            in = args[arg_index++].toCharArray();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0, j = 256; i < in.length; i++, j++) {
                            mem[j] = in[i];
                        }
                        break;

                    case CANVAS:
                        if (interactive) {
                            Canvas.createCanvas(
                                evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0),
                                evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 1),
                                texts[tokens[3]]
                            );
                        }
                        break;
                    case WAIT:
                        Thread.sleep(evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0));
                        break;
                    case DRAW:
                        if (Canvas.createdCanvas) {
                            int startX = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0);
                            int startY = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 1);
                            int widthX = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[3], 2);
                            int widthY = evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[4], 3);
                            double a = widthX * widthX / 4;
                            double b = widthY * widthY / 4;
                            boolean square = ((tokens[0] >> 4) & 1) == Silos.SQUARE;
                            for (int i = startX; i < startX + widthX; i++) {
                                for (int j = startY; j < startY + widthY; j++) {
                                    int xC = i - (startX + widthX / 2);
                                    int yC = j - (startY + widthY / 2);
                                    if (square || ((xC * xC) / a) + ((yC * yC) / b) < 1) {
                                        if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i < Canvas.canvas.length && j < Canvas.canvas[i].length) {
                                            Canvas.canvas[i][j] = Canvas.pen;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case PEN:
                        if (Canvas.createdCanvas) {
                            Canvas.pen = new Color(
                                evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[1], 0),
                                evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[2], 1),
                                evalToken(tokens[0], tokens[3], 2)
                            );
                        }
                        break;
                    case BIND:
                        Input.setNewBindings(tokens);
                        break;
                    case REFRESH:
                        if (Canvas.createdCanvas) {
                            Canvas.c.repaint();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                ptr++;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //praise vb "on error resume next"!
                ptr++;
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    static class Canvas extends JFrame {

        static class Panel extends JPanel {

            public static ArrayList<Drawable> toDraw = new ArrayList<>();

            public Panel(int inX, int inY) {
                x = inX;
                y = inY;
            }
            public int x, y;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                for (Drawable d : toDraw) {
                    g.setColor(d.color);
                    if (d.type == 1) {
                        g.fillOval(d.x, d.y, d.width, d.height);
                    } else {
                        g.fillRect(d.x, d.y, d.width, d.height);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(x, y);
            }
        }
        public static Color[][] canvas;
        public static Color pen = Color.black;
        static boolean createdCanvas = false;
        public static Canvas c;

        private Canvas(int x, int y, String message) {
            super(message);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.add(new Panel(x, y));
            this.pack();
            this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.addKeyListener(new Input());
        }

        public static void createCanvas(int x, int y, String message) {
            if (!createdCanvas) {
                createdCanvas = true;
                canvas = new Color[x][y];
                for (int i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < canvas[i].length; j++) {
                        canvas[i][j] = Color.white;
                    }
                }
                c = new Canvas(x, y, message);
            }
        }
    }
    static int[] memory;

    /**
     *
     * @param fileName is the path to the file or just the name if it is local
     * @return an array of Strings where each string is one line from the file
     * fileName.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static int[][] compile(String fileName) {
        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File textFile = new File(fileName);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(textFile);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                tokens.add(sc.nextLine().replaceAll("^\\s+", ""));
            }
            sc.close();
            List program = new ArrayList();
            String[] replace = new String[]{""};
            if (tokens.size() > 1 && tokens.get(1).startsWith("def")) {
                replace = tokens.remove(1).split(" ");
            }
            if (tokens.size() > 0) {
                try {
                    mem = new int[Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(0))];
                    tokens.remove(0);
                }//allocates the memory on the first line of code
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    mem = new int[8192];//default size if there is no allocation specified
                }
            }
            ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> label_pos = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> label_temp = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> funcs = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> func_pos = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> func_temp = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                String command = tokens.get(i);
                if (command.startsWith("def")
                    || command.startsWith("//")
                    || command.startsWith("#")
                    || command.startsWith("*")
                    || command.startsWith("/*")
                ) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (int j = 1; j < replace.length; j += 2) {
                    command = command.replaceAll(replace[j], replace[j + 1]);
                }
                if (command.length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (command.startsWith("lbl")) {
                    if (command.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                        //GOTO only takes the first token
                        //if label has space, it will never be accessed
                        continue;
                    }
                    String label = command.substring(3);
                    if (labels.contains(label)) {
                        System.err.println("The label " + label + " is repeated in line " + (i + 1) + ".");
                        //only use the first occurrence
                        continue;
                    }
                    labels.add(label);
                    label_pos.add(program.size());
                    continue;
                }
                if (command.startsWith("func")) {
                    if (command.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                        //GOSUB only takes the first token
                        //if function name has space, it will never be accessed
                        continue;
                    }
                    String func = command.substring(4);
                    if (funcs.contains(func)) {
                        System.err.println("The function name " + func + " is repeated in line " + (i + 1) + ".");
                        //only use the first occurrence
                        continue;
                    }
                    funcs.add(func);
                    func_pos.add(program.size());
                    continue;
                }
                String command_clone = new String(command);
                command = command.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
                if (command.length() > 1) {
                    switch (command.charAt(1)) {
                        case '+':
                        case '-':
                        case '*':
                        case '/':
                        case '%':
                        case '^':
                        case '=':
                        case '|':
                        case '&':
                        case ':':
                        case '!':
                        case '?':
                        case '~':
                        case '<':
                        case '>':
                            command = command.charAt(0) + " " + command.substring(1);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (command.length() > 2) {
                    switch (command.charAt(2)) {
                        case '+':
                        case '-':
                        case '*':
                        case '/':
                        case '%':
                        case '^':
                        case '=':
                        case '|':
                        case '&':
                        case ':':
                        case '!':
                        case '?':
                        case '~':
                        case '<':
                        case '>':
                            if (command.length() > 3 && command.charAt(3) != ' ') {
                                command = command.substring(0, 3) + " " + command.substring(3);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                String[] words = command.split(" ");
                if (words.length == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                String instruction = words[0];
                //control flows
                if (instruction.equals("GOTO")) {
                    String label = words[1];
                    int index = label_temp.indexOf(label);
                    if (index == -1) {
                        index = label_temp.size();
                        label_temp.add(label);
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.GOTO, index});
                }
                if (instruction.equals("GOSUB")) {
                    String func = words[1];
                    int index = func_temp.indexOf(func);
                    if (index == -1) {
                        index = func_temp.size();
                        func_temp.add(func);
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.GOSUB, index});
                    continue;
                }

                //IO
                if (instruction.equals("readIO")) {
                    if (command_clone.length() > 7) {
                        String text = command_clone.substring(7);
                        int index = texts.indexOf(text);
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = texts.size();
                            texts.add(text);
                        }
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.READIO, index});
                    } else {
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.READIO});
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("loadLine")) {
                    if (command_clone.length() > 9) {
                        String text = command_clone.substring(9);
                        int index = texts.indexOf(text);
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = texts.size();
                            texts.add(text);
                        }
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.LOADLINE, index});
                    } else {
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.LOADLINE});
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("print")) {
                    if (command_clone.length() > 6) {
                        String text = command_clone.substring(6);
                        int index = texts.indexOf(text);
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = texts.size();
                            texts.add(text);
                        }
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINT, index});
                    } else {
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINT});
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("printLine")) {
                    if (command_clone.length() > 10) {
                        String text = command_clone.substring(10);
                        int index = texts.indexOf(text);
                        if (index == -1) {
                            index = texts.size();
                            texts.add(text);
                        }
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINTLINE, index});
                    } else {
                        program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINTLINE});
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                //no arguments
                if (instruction.equals("return")) {
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.RETURN});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("refresh")) {
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.REFRESH});
                    continue;
                }

                //one argument
                if (instruction.equals("printChar")) {
                    int mode;
                    int argument;
                    try {
                        argument = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        argument = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINTCHAR + mode, argument});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("printInt")) {
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINTINT + Silos.VARIABLE, (int) words[1].charAt(0)});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("printIntNoLine")) {
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.PRINTINTNOLINE + Silos.VARIABLE, (int) words[1].charAt(0)});
                    continue;
                }

                if (instruction.equals("get")) {
                    int mode;
                    int argument;
                    try {
                        argument = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        argument = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.GET + mode, argument});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("rand")) {
                    int mode;
                    int argument;
                    try {
                        argument = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        argument = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.RAND + mode, argument});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("wait")) {
                    int mode;
                    int argument;
                    try {
                        argument = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        argument = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.WAIT + mode, argument});
                    continue;
                }

                //two arguments
                if (instruction.equals("if")) {
                    int mode;
                    int check;
                    try {
                        check = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        check = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    String label = words[2];
                    int index = label_temp.indexOf(label);
                    if (index == -1) {
                        index = label_temp.size();
                        label_temp.add(label);
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.IF + mode, check, index});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("set")) {
                    int mode1, mode2;
                    int arg1, arg2;
                    try {
                        arg1 = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode1 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg1 = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode1 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        mode2 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                        mode2 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.SET + (mode2 << 1) + (mode1), arg1, arg2});
                    continue;
                }

                //three arguments
                if (instruction.equals("canvas")) {
                    int mode1, mode2;
                    int arg1, arg2;
                    try {
                        arg1 = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode1 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg1 = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode1 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        mode2 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                        mode2 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    String text = words[words.length - 1];
                    int index = texts.indexOf(text);
                    if (index == -1) {
                        index = texts.size();
                        texts.add(text);
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.CANVAS + (mode2 << 1) + (mode1), arg1, arg2, index});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("pen")) {
                    int mode1, mode2, mode3;
                    int arg1, arg2, arg3;
                    try {
                        arg1 = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode1 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg1 = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode1 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        mode2 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                        mode2 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg3 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
                        mode3 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg3 = (int) words[3].charAt(0);
                        mode3 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.PEN + (mode3 << 2) + (mode2 << 1) + (mode1), arg1, arg2, arg3});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("newObj")) {
                    int mode1, mode2, mode3;
                    int arg1, arg2, arg3;
                    try {
                        arg1 = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode1 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg1 = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode1 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        mode2 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                        mode2 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg3 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
                        mode3 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg3 = (int) words[3].charAt(0);
                        mode3 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.NEWOBJ + (mode3 << 2) + (mode2 << 1) + (mode1), arg1, arg2, arg3});
                    continue;
                }
                if (instruction.equals("moveObj")) {
                    int mode1, mode2, mode3;
                    int arg1, arg2, arg3;
                    try {
                        arg1 = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                        mode1 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg1 = (int) words[1].charAt(0);
                        mode1 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        mode2 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                        mode2 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg3 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
                        mode3 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg3 = (int) words[3].charAt(0);
                        mode3 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.MOVEOBJ + (mode3 << 2) + (mode2 << 1) + (mode1), arg1, arg2, arg3});
                    continue;
                }
                //five arguments
                if (instruction.equals("draw")) {
                    int mode1, mode2, mode3, mode4;
                    int arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4;
                    int shape;
                    if (words[1].equals("square")) {
                        shape = Silos.SQUARE;
                    } else {
                        shape = Silos.ELLIPSE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg1 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        mode1 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg1 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                        mode1 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
                        mode2 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg2 = (int) words[3].charAt(0);
                        mode2 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg3 = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
                        mode3 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg3 = (int) words[4].charAt(0);
                        mode3 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    try {
                        arg4 = Integer.parseInt(words[5]);
                        mode4 = Silos.INTEGER;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        arg4 = (int) words[5].charAt(0);
                        mode4 = Silos.VARIABLE;
                    }
                    program.add(new int[]{Silos.DRAW + (shape << 4) + (mode4 << 3) + (mode3 << 2) + (mode2 << 1) + (mode1), arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4});
                    continue;
                }

                //please
                if (instruction.equals("bind")) {
                    int[] bindings = new int[words.length * 2 + 1];
                    bindings[0] = Silos.BIND;
                    for (int j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
                        int mode, argument;
                        try {
                            argument = Integer.parseInt(words[j]);
                            mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            argument = (int) words[j].charAt(0);
                            mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                        }
                        bindings[j * 2 - 1] = mode;
                        bindings[j * 2] = argument;
                    }
                    program.add(bindings);
                }

                //arithmetics (and assignments)
                if (instruction.length() > 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (words[1].length() > 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                int instr = -1;
                int mode = -1;
                int arg1 = (int) instruction.charAt(0);
                int arg2 = -1;
                switch (words[1].charAt(0)) {
                    case '+':
                        instr = Silos.ADD;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        instr = Silos.SUB;
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        instr = Silos.MUL;
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        instr = Silos.DIV;
                        break;
                    case '%':
                        instr = Silos.MOD;
                        break;
                    case '^':
                        instr = Silos.POW;
                        break;
                    case '|':
                        instr = Silos.ABS;
                        break;
                    case '=':
                        instr = Silos.ASSIGN;
                        break;
                    case '&':
                        instr = Silos.AND;
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        instr = Silos.OR;
                        break;
                    case '!':
                        instr = Silos.XOR;
                        break;
                    case '?':
                        instr = Silos.XNOR;
                        break;
                    case '~':
                        instr = Silos.NOT;
                        break;
                    case '<':
                        instr = Silos.LSHIFT;
                        break;
                    case '>':
                        instr = Silos.RSHIFT;
                        break;
                }
                if (instr >= 0) {
                    if (instr == Silos.ABS || instr == Silos.NOT) {
                        program.add(new int[]{instr, arg1});
                    } else if (instr == Silos.ASSIGN) {
                        try {
                            arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                            mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            try {
                                try {
                                    arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
                                    mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    arg2 = (int) words[3].charAt(0);
                                    mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                                }
                                instr = Silos.GET;
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                                mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                            }
                        }
                        program.add(new int[]{instr + mode, arg1, arg2});
                    } else {
                        try {
                            arg2 = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                            mode = Silos.INTEGER;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            arg2 = (int) words[2].charAt(0);
                            mode = Silos.VARIABLE;
                        }
                        program.add(new int[]{instr + mode, arg1, arg2});
                    }
                }
            }
            //labels and function names
            for (int i = 0; i < program.size(); i++) {
                int[] instruction = (int[]) program.get(i);
                String label;
                int index;
                switch (instruction[0] & ~0b11111111) {
                    case GOTO:
                        label = label_temp.get(instruction[1]);
                        index = labels.indexOf(label);
                        if (index >= 0) {
                            instruction[1] = label_pos.get(index);
                        } else {
                            instruction[1] = i;
                        }
                        break;
                    case IF:
                        label = label_temp.get(instruction[2]);
                        index = labels.indexOf(label);
                        if (index >= 0) {
                            instruction[2] = label_pos.get(index);
                        } else {
                            instruction[2] = i;
                        }
                        break;
                    case GOSUB:
                        label = func_temp.get(instruction[1]);
                        index = funcs.indexOf(label);
                        if (index >= 0) {
                            instruction[1] = func_pos.get(index);
                        } else {
                            instruction[1] = i;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            Silos.texts = texts.toArray(new String[texts.size()]);
            return (int[][]) program.toArray(new int[program.size()][]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
public static String program = "";
    /**
     * Evaluates a token by figuring out whether it is an integer literal or a
     * variable
     *
     * @param mode, argument, index
     * @return the value of the token
     */
    private static int evalToken(int mode, int argument, int index) {
        return ((mode >> index) & 1) == VARIABLE ? mem[argument] : argument;
    }

}
```

The documentation is available [here](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S/tree/e6c1b41dc1cc56b064618f0e72952f8694ca1120).